# Why Akamai WhoAmI Tool show that 1.1.1. supoort ECS?

Tags: networking, dns

Akamai whoami tools can check whether a DNS resolver support EDNS-client subnet. The following result shows that 1.1.1.1 do support ECS.

```
ec2-user@ip-172-31-42-222 ~]$ dig +short TXT whoami.ds.akahelp.net @1.1.1.1
"ecs" "54.73.0.0/24/24"
"ip" "54.73.0.168"
"ns" "162.158.37.98"
```

However, according to the CloudFlare FAQ, it should not support ECS.

> 1.1.1.1 is a privacy centric resolver so it does not send any client IP information and does not send the EDNS Client Subnet Header to
> authoritative servers.
>
> https://developers.cloudflare.com/1.1.1.1/faq/#does-1111-send-edns-client-subnet-header

Try [another tool](https://support.google.com/interconnect/answer/7658602?hl=en) provide by Google. It shows that 1.1.1.1 doesn't support ECS (no any ECS information responded).

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-42-222 ~]$ dig +short TXT o-o.myaddr.l.google.com @1.1.1.1
"162.158.37.35"
```

So, is Akamai's tool wrong? How can I explain the conflict?

Comment: I would send that akamai output to cloudflare and ask them.

Answer (score 1):

I ask the same question in CloudFlare community. CloudFlare treats Akamai test server as a special case.

https://community.cloudflare.com/t/why-akamai-whoami-tool-show-that-1-1-1-supoort-ecs/389954

> The exception is the single Akamai debug domain whoami.ds.akahelp.net to aid in cross-provider debugging. However, Cloudflare does not send ECS to any of Akamai’s production domains, such as akamaihd.net or similar. https://developers.cloudflare.com/1.1.1.1/faq/#does-1111-send-edns-client-subnet-header